# GridView highlighting incorrect position when clicked

Tags: android, gridview, highlight

I'm trying to have a GridView of images that can be clicked to trigger various event. The GridView is supposed to automatically highlight which cell I press.

The problem is that while the correct cell actually gets pressed, the highlight effect shows up on a different cell. For most (but not all) rows in the GridView the highlight occurs on the first cell in the row regardless of which cell is actually pressed.

What could be causing this?

Comment: unless we see your code, how do we know whats causing what! please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

A few things. Either your not doing your findViewByIds on the actual view that is passed in. Check that you are doing view.findViewById() And also make sure you are returning the correct object from getItem(int position). Ie don't just return position, deference your data and actually return in object.

Answer (score 0):

GridView recycles its content, i.e. something at position 0 can have multiple values depending on the state of the application //scroll etc

GridView only stores the content that is presently visible on screen

You'll have to edit your adapter code for the intended behaviour

Refer to: [GridView get view by position, first child view different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548276/gridview-get-view-by-position-first-child-view-different)