# Fetching the view at a position of a GridView gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

I have an activity which is populated by a `GridView` containing a ***3x3 matrix*** 
of `LinearLayouts` (which in turn have `ImageViews`). When I try to get a position 
of view after some the `GridView` is completely loaded, I get proper results.

However, when I try to fetch the view at a given position from `onResume()`,
it gives a `NullPointerException`. Why does this happen? Isn't the `GridView`
initialized by the time `onResume()` is called?

Are there any workaround for this?

The part where I am trying to fetch the view of a given position -

```
private void systemsMove(String userBlock) {
    int position, row, column;
    String systemsBlock = (userBlock.equalsIgnoreCase("Zero") ? "One" : "Zero");

    for (position = 0, row = 0, column = 0;
            (mModel.array[row][column] == 0
                 || mModel.array[row][column] == 1) && position < 9; 
                      position++) {
        row = position / MAX_COLUMN;
        column = position % MAX_COLUMN;
    }
    if (position == 9) finish();
    mModel.changeBlock(systemsBlock, row, column);

    View view = getViewByPosition(position);
    if (view == null)
        Log.i(TAG, "The view is NULL!!!");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    if (systemsBlock.equalsIgnoreCase("Zero"))
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    else if (systemsBlock.equalsIgnoreCase("One"))
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.zero);
}
```

Code that works from `OnItemClickListener` -

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, 
            long id) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        String systemBlock = "";

        if (userBlock.equalsIgnoreCase("One")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
            systemBlock = "Zero";
        } else if (userBlock.equalsIgnoreCase("Zero")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.zero);
            systemBlock = "One";
        }

        int row = position / MAX_COLUMN;
        int column = position % MAX_COLUMN;
        mModel.changeBlock(userBlock, row, column);
        if (mModel.checkForWin()) {
            mModel.deInitialize();
            finish();
        }

        systemsMove(systemBlock);
        if (mModel.checkForWin()) {
            mModel.deInitialize();
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

Method for getting View for a position in a `GridView` from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20591089) -

```
public View getViewByPosition(int position) {
    int firstPosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastPosition = gridView.getLastVisiblePosition();

    if ((position < firstPosition) || (position > lastPosition))
        return null;

    return gridView.getChildAt(position - firstPosition);
}
```

And this is how I call it from `onResume()` -

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    String userBlock = getIntent().getStringExtra("BlockSelected");
    if (userBlock.equalsIgnoreCase("Zero")) systemsMove(userBlock);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GridView will populate itself from the adapter during the first layout pass. This means it won't have children in onCreate(). The easiest way to wait for the first layout pass is to use a ViewTreeObserver (see View.getViewTreeObserver()) to register a global layout listener. The first time the listener is invoked, the grid should contain children.

Note that if you want to change the background of one of the children of a GridView you really should do it from the adapter. Since views are recycled the background may appear to "move" to another view later on